# List index out of range

Tags: python, mysql, list, numpy, dictionary

So I am calling some data through SQL queries and I am running into an error of list index range when attempting to loop through it, normalizing and plotting it.

Here's my SQLs:

```
s1 = db.dict.execute("SELECT sp.wavelength, sp.flux, spt.spectral_type, s.designation, s.shortname, s.names FROM spectra AS sp JOIN sources AS s ON sp.source_id=s.id JOIN spectral_types as spt ON spt.source_id=s.id WHERE sp.instrument_id=6 AND sp.mode_id=2 AND 10<spt.spectral_type<19").fetchall()
s2 = db.dict.execute("SELECT sp.wavelength, sp.flux, spt.spectral_type, s.designation, s.shortname, s.names FROM spectra AS sp JOIN sources AS s ON sp.source_id=s.id JOIN spectral_types as spt ON spt.source_id=s.id WHERE sp.instrument_id=9 AND sp.wavelength_order='n3' AND 10<spt.spectral_type<19").fetchall()
s3 = db.dict.execute("SELECT sp.wavelength, sp.flux, spt.spectral_type, s.designation, s.shortname, s.names FROM spectra AS sp JOIN sources AS s ON sp.source_id=s.id JOIN spectral_types as spt ON spt.source_id=s.id WHERE sp.instrument_id=16 AND 10<spt.spectral_type<19").fetchall()
```

Then I am combining them into S:

```
S = s1+s2+s3
```

Finally, I want to loop through them to normalize, trim and plot all the entries in the dictionary I called.

```
for n,i in enumerate(S):
    W,F = S[n]['wavelength'], S[n]['flux'] # here I define wavelength and flux from SQL query "S"
    band = [1.15,1.325] #The range at which I want to normalize, see next line
    S1 = at.norm_spec([W,F], band) # here I normalize W and F and define S1 as the normalized W,F
    W3 = S1[n][0] #here I define a new W and F but from the normalized S1 spectrum file
    F3 = S1[n][1] 
    W2,F2 =[p[np.where(np.logical_and(W3>1.15, W3<1.325))] for p in [W3,F3]] #here I trim the noisy ends of data and narrow to a small range
    z = np.polyfit(W2, F2, 3) #from here on it's just fitting polynomials and plotting
    f = np.poly1d(z)
    yvalue = 6*(max(F2)/9)
    xvalue = 6*(max(W2)/9)
    W_new = np.linspace(W2[0], W2[-1], 5000)
    F_new = f(W_new)
    plt.ylabel('Flux F$_{\lambda}$')
    plt.xlabel('Wavelength ($\mu$m)')
    name= S[n]['designation']
    name2= S[n]['shortname']
    name3= S[n]['names']
    plt.annotate('{0} \n Spectral type: {1}'.format(S[n][('designation' or 'shortname' or 'names')], S[n]['spectral_type']), xy=(xvalue, yvalue), xytext=(xvalue, yvalue), color='black')
    #plt.figure()
    plt.plot(W2,F2, 'k-', W_new, F_new, 'g-')
```

Now, it goes through the first iteration, meaning it plots S1[0][0] and S1[0][1], but it breaks and says S1[1][0] and S1[1][1] is out of range:
    61         print len(S1)
    62         #print S1[n]['wavelength']

```
--->63         W3 = S1[n][0] #here I define a new W and F but from the normalized S1 spectrum file
64         F3 = S1[n][1]
65         W2,F2 =[p[np.where(np.logical_and(W3>1.15, W3<1.325))] for p in [W3,F3]] #here I trim the noisy ends and narrow to potassium lines

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I really don't see where my error is in this, any help will be appreciated!

Sara

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your code well, firstly you're iterating over 'n' objects of S, but then S1 is a whole new object which quantity isn't "n", but some other (length of this vector, or something). Maybe just `W3 = S1[0]` would be correct? Though, I don't know what `at.norm_spec` and what type of object is returnig, so I'm only guessing.

Suggestion: Write (more) meaningful variables in your code. It's **really, really** hard to read something like that and it's **very, very** easy to made a mistake writing that kind of code. And it's not pythonic.

Comment: Hi, thank you for responding. The solution was actually writing `W3=S1[0][0] and `F3=S1[0][1]`, but your explanation really helped me understand where I went wrong.